# html button onclick function is not working in html.erb environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I want to execute a jar file after getting some input from the web page on button click in html.erb environment(ruby on rails). But it runs the jar file at the time of loading the page (even before button click and button is not working after I clicked).

```
<br>
<div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info unpressed" type="button", onclick="<%= %x(java -jar /home/Dev/Desktop/justButton/conceptMapEditor/public/demone.jar) %> " style="width:50%">CJF</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i advise you to work with JavaScript function, put an id on your button, like id="my_button_id" and do this:

```
<script>
  $('#button_id').on('click', function(){
    your event goes here
  });
```

Comment: I tried in two ways but the result is still same. Could you please suggest by having look at these snippets.    `<br>
    <div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFirst()" type="button">CJF!</button>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(myFirst(){
    $("btn").on('click', myFirst(){
      <%= %x(java -jar /home/Dev/Desktop/justButton/conceptMapEditor/public/demone.jar) %> 
    });

  </script>`

Comment: Second Method:    `    <br>
    <div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFirst()" type="button">CJF!</button>


    <script>
    function myFirst() {
       document.getElementById("btn").onclick =  <%= %x(java -jar /home/Dev/Desktop/justButton/conceptMapEditor/public/demone.jar) %> 
    }
    
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Bro the selector must have this form $("#id") to work.

Answer (score 0):

To test what i'm saying copy and paste this code:

```
<button id="my_button">
  Enviar
</button>

<script>
  $('#my_button').on('click', function(){
    alert("Hola");
  });
</script>
```